# Can databases with different collations get along on one server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, collation

So I have two SQL Servers at the moment, both 2012 and both running separate systems.

One of these servers runs on a collation of latin1_general_bin and the other runs with `latin1_general_ci_as`, ideally I'd like to shut one of these servers off and move all the systems to one place.

I know this can be done technically, however I was wondering if this was a good idea? Will I be causing myself more problems down the line?

Both databases are transactional based and are defined by external parties so cannot have their collation changed. If I were as to do this, would it be better to have the server collation set as `latin1_general_bin` or `latin1_general_ci_as`? I'm thinking that the case sensitive option would be better as queries would still run against case insensitive databases whilst case insensitive queries would need to be carefully managed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no problem using databases with different collations on one server. One of our external vendors also provides a database with different collation and this has been working without issues since SQL Server 2000. However, you will have to explicitly specify the collation (or use `collation database_default` when you want to join tables from the different databases. From my own experience, that can have quite a performance impact. You also need to be careful when using `SELECT INTO` when creating a new table as this can result in mixed collation in a database or table.

Comment: Thanks for this, what collation would you suggest for the server itself and why?

Comment: Jaco, keep in mind, that also `CREATE TABLE #Tbl(...` may cause big troubles...+1 form my side

Comment: You can set the collation at database level, however, there is a performance penalty when you have a mismatch of server collation and database collation. Which is the biggest database?

Comment: @Jaco - I'm assuming that the case insensitive ones will be the larger of the databases (the case sensitive db belongs to a new product) - is the performance penalty caused by cross-db queries or is it every transaction?

Comment: The overhead occurs when joining on temporary tables that are created with the server's default collation instead of the database's default collation.

Comment: @ChrisJ, Collations turn into effect whenever a textual column is used for filtering, joining, check constraints... I would not bother to much about performance. But - if you really mix this - you will have to think about this **whenever you write a SQL command !!!** You'll have to type the collation hundreds of times which is erronous and may lead to hardly traceable exceptions... I would try not to mix collations if there's a way around...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SQL Server keeps the collation neatly separated with the databases. But there is a big flaw, which caused **severe problems** with one of our customers:

The **temp table** (`CREATE TABLE #Tbl ...`) uses the server's default collation if you do not specify the collation explicitly.

In one of our projects, especially with quite old stored Procedures created with SQL Server 2000, there was heavy usage of temp tables to store intermediate results.

The customer ran into crazy errors and it took a hell of a lot of time to track this down. He did not want to change his server (due to other databases running there). So we changed the database to his collation. After this some of our upgrade scripts did not run anymore... It ended with all databases changed to the same collation and the installation of another instance of SQL Server.

Which collation is the best for you? I don't know... This depends on your needs. Are you dealing with diacritic characters a lot (look at "_as"), do you want "test" to be equal with "TeSt" (look at "_ci")