# what are the possible Impact of changing column collate in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database, linq, t-sql

I'm using MSSQL 2012,

To handle special character in searching through LINQ, i found to change COLLATE of the column to *_CI_AI, but before changing it i would like to know what and where its impact.

Comment: Hi, is this question solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: @Shnugo : It's solved but i want to know it's impact.

Comment: I added a list...

Comment: The collation is either correct for your purposes or incorrect. What exactly are you looking for, beyond "the database goes from being incorrect to being correct"?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Collation is correct and works for me, but i want's to is is going to affect any other queries?

Comment: @Shnugo Thankyou, i'll looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be not so easy...

If this column takes part in indexes and constraints you will have to drop them, change the collation and recreate them.

One very painfull point with collations is the fact, that the temp-db uses - by default - the default-collation of the server-instance. We once had a project, where after such a step certain statements ran into errors. This happened, when a Stored Procedure created a `#table' and used such a column in any kind of comparison (in` WHERE`or`JOIN`-predicat).

You **can type the collation in any statement manually**, so it will be possible to get things working, but **the effort might be huge**...

Some related answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39101572/5089204
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35840417/5089204

### UPDATE a list if effects / impacts

- sorting might change (a sorted list could appear in a different order)
- comparisons will be less restrictive with `_CI_AI`. "Peter" eq. to "peter". Sometimes this is OK (most of the time actually), but not always (imagine a password). In cases where "Pétè" should be the same as "Pete" this helps...
- Joins on string base might join differently (If ProductCode "aBx5" is not the same code as "ABx5")
- Check-Constraints might be less restrictive (you force values "A","B" or "C" and suddenly you may insert "a","b" and "c"...)
- You might run (**this can be very annoying!**) into collation errors in connection with temp tables. This can break existing code...

With simple text columns this should be not problem...

Comment: Thank you, got the point and it will be useful to track the changes. #happycoding